# Place to store luggage for the day in Tokyo?

Tags: japan, tokyo, luggage-storage

I'm switching airports between Haneda and Narita over the course of 30 hours. As a result I have the day in Tokyo.  I'm likely sleeping in the airport, so don't have a hotel in town to store my bags at.

Any ideas on luggage storage? Eg the train stations to  the airports - would they have storage?

Comment: It's looking like Shinjuku may be the place, although I'm still having a search.

Comment: You don't want to go to Shinjuku even if they have a thousand lockers there. It's not on the way, and the amount of people will ensure that you don't get an empty locker. How much luggage will you have?

Comment: A large backpack, and a day pack, but I'll keep the day pack with me.  The monorail from Haneda looks like it goes straight to Shinjuku - not a good idea?

Comment: Are you planning some sight-seeing in Shinjuku? If you're only changing airports, then you should do JR Narita Express to Shingawa and then Keikyu Main Line to Haneda.

Comment: I have a day in Tokyo, so basically any central station will work. I'll come in from Haneda, explore, then get the train to Narita that night.

Comment: Oh alright, then Shinjuku/Shibuya/Tokyo Station are the best options. :)

Comment: Also, take a look at this [link](https://www.jreast.co.jp/e/customer_support/service_center_tokyo.html). I would suggest Tokyo station is great for sightseeing and luggage storage as well. Shinjuku is a bustly area, you can visit there but I wouldn't suggest storing your luggage there..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easy, safe and cheap option is **train station lockers**, which can be found at all major train stations in Tokyo (and Japan).  Japanese lockers are usually narrow but deep, so while hard plastic suitcases will not fit into them, backpacks are generally not a problem.  Some larger stations (eg. Tokyo stn) also have manned left luggage counters (手荷物預かり所 *nimotsu-azukari-dokoro*), which can handle any size of bag and only cost a bit more than lockers.  On station maps, these are usually shown with a "bag-and-key" icon, while lockers are "bag-in-box-with-key".

Which one to recommend, though, is going to depend on what you were going to do during your day in Tokyo and how you're planning to get around.

- If you're planning on exploring around **Shibuya or Shinjuku**, I'd take the Keikyu railway from Haneda and leave the bag at **Shinagawa**.  Shibuya and Shinjuku are a few stops away on the Yamanote line, and you can continue to Narita directly on the JR Narita Express (N'EX).
- Alternatively, you can transfer from Shinagawa to Shibuya/Shinjuku with your bag, leave it at either station, and then take the N'EX.
- If you're planning on exploring around **Ueno and Asakusa**, I'd take the monorail to Hamamatsucho, connect to Yamanote, and leave the bag at **Ueno**.  Ueno Park is walking distance, Asakusa is a few stops away on the Ginza Line, and you can continue to Narita directly on the Keisei Skyliner (premium) or Sky Access Limited Express (cheaper, slower).
- You can also take the Keikyu line via Shinagawa directly to Asakusa, but this takes approximately forever and may require a transfer along the way.

I probably would *not* recommend Tokyo station: it's huge, remarkably confusing, not terribly close to anything interesting (although naturally it's well connected to the entire city), and not super easy to get to from Haneda.  That said, there are [very cheap buses](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tokyo_Narita_Airport#Keisei_Bus) from Tokyo stn to Narita, so if you're really pinching pennies it *might* be worth hassle.

One tip: when you do leave your bag, pay careful attention to where the locker is and how you got there, these are all massive stations and (voice of experience) it's no fun running around trying to figure out where the hell you left it...

Comment: Tokyo station may have a larger amount of lockers and availability of luggage handling whereas Shinagawa may not have either. Check this link for [JR East](https://www.jreast.co.jp/e/customer_support/service_center_tokyo.html)

Comment: Also, Shinagawa is great for traveling but the OP is short on time, which might make Shinagawa an unnecessary trip because there isn't a lot to see there.

Comment: Also, just so you can add to your answer, I'd suggest that no one, NO ONE should carry their bags in Yamanote ever. That man would die a slow and painful death. It's the busiest line on the planet.

Comment: Shinagawa has plenty of lockers, see http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/stations/e788.html, and I'm suggesting it because it's central and very easily reached from Haneda.  Bags on the Yamanote are no problem outside rush hour, just don't try this at 8 AM...

Comment: My experience with Yamanote has been that there is always rush hour on Yamanote. But of course, 8AM is hell. Also, finding large lockers at either place will a big pain. OP has a large backpack which may or may not fit in the large lockers. :/ Using the baggage services at Tokyo may mitigate this issue.

Comment: They have coin lockers at the airport too; you could also use those.

Comment: @emodendroket, the OP is transiting from Haneda to Narita, which means they'd have to return to get the bags.

Answer (score 3):

There is a recent service called [Ecbo Cloak](https://cloak.ecbo.io/en) which eliminates two of the biggest unknowns regarding coin lockers in Tokyo.

You can usually check large items; and, you can also make a reservation so you don't have to hope that there's an opening.

It basically hooks you up with a nearby restaurant, hotel, internet cafe, etc which has committed some storage space either behind their desk, in the back room, or wherever.  Kinda like Uber for coin lockers.  There are locations all around the city, and likely to find one near your hotel or train station.