# Is there a comprehensive map of the Shinjuku station in Tokyo?

Tags: trains, japan, maps, tokyo, train-stations

According to [wikipedia's article on Shinjuku station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinjuku_Station), *including an underground arcade, there are well over 200 exits*.

http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/stations/img/map_e/e866.pdf mentions a few exits but the fact that the "East Exit" exits into the Metro Promenade, which in turn, takes you to an underground shopping mall, with its own exits, as well (http://www.subnade.co.jp/english/e-floormap.pdf), is not accounted for. I'm sure there are other examples, as well, but I'm not aware of them.

In light of this it'd be useful to have a fully comprehensive map of the Shinjuku station and associated facilities and all the exists there-in. I don't suppose such a map exists?

It'd also be cool if such a map could show you where each of these exists exited, at street level, on Google Maps, but that might be too much to hope for lol.

Comment: Sounds like a challenge to make one of these! There are exits to the street, exits to underground concourses, exits to shopping malls, exits on upper floors, exits currently under construction (but different ones are under construction this year than last year), and all this for at least 5 or 6 different train companies that I can think of off the cuff!

Comment: [I stored a bag there last year](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30849/place-to-store-luggage-for-the-day-in-tokyo) near the west exit. Returned that evening and came out east side.  Took me way longer than I felt comfortable with to locate the rack of lockers with my stuff again - that station is a maze!

Comment: Any such map would only be up to date for a total of 38 nanoseconds before another wormhole ... I mean ... exit is created.

Answer (score 8):

The trouble with Shinjuku Station is that it's split between four different companies (JR, Metro, Odakyu, Keio), so there's no one official map that covers the lot, and the very three-dimensional layout of the station means that flat/2D maps don't come close to conveying the full complexity of this beast.  This rather amazing hand-drawn 3D sketch is the best I've seen, although it's all Japanese:

[image]
(courtesy [Tomoyuki Tanaka](http://www.spoon-tamago.com/2016/06/27/illustrated-cross-sections-of-major-train-stations-in-tokyo-by-tomoyuki-tanaka/), [high-res B&W version here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Tokyo/comments/82uy3d/3d_plan_of_shinjuku_station_by_tomoyuki_tanaka/))

Official maps for each train company, covering only their respective parts in both 3D/structural (立体図) and flat format (平面図) below:

1. [JR East](https://www.jreast.co.jp/estation/stations/866.html), red in the diagram above
2. [Keio](https://www.keio.co.jp/train/station/station_map/pdf/ksb01_shinjuku.pdf) (PDF), green
3. [Odakyu](https://www.odakyu.jp/station/shinjuku/), blue
4. [Tokyo Metro](https://www.tokyometro.jp/station/shinjuku/yardmap/index.html), pink

Note that the colors apply only to paid/ticketed spaces in the stations, all the purple parts are free to cross without a ticket.

Bonus: a [wooden model of Shinjuku station's pathways](https://dailyportalz.jp/kiji/161122198124), built by a very determined group at Showa Women's University.

Comment: Apparently the image you posted is done by a guy named Tomoyuki Tanaka and was part of an exhibition in Tokyo: http://www.spoon-tamago.com/2016/06/27/illustrated-cross-sections-of-major-train-stations-in-tokyo-by-tomoyuki-tanaka/ A higher res non-colorized version is available on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Tokyo/comments/82uy3d/3d_plan_of_shinjuku_station_by_tomoyuki_tanaka/ . Would be neat to get it translated!

Comment: @neubert Thank you so much!  I was looking for the author but couldn't find the original even with reverse image search.

Answer (score 6):

The linked JR map in the question is one of the easier sections of the station to navigate, in my opinion.  I've gotten "re-oriented" in the underground areas more times than I care to admit, and it is sometimes easiest to just go outside, find a landmark, and walk in that direction.

There is a map of all the platforms (JR, Keio, Odakyu, Toei, and Metro) [here](http://www.keio.co.jp/english/howto/shinjuku/pdf/ksb01_shinjuku.pdf)
<s>but, I don't know of any comprehensive map of the non-platform areas.</s>

I just found a nice [set of underground maps](http://map.yahoo.co.jp/chika?ac=13) at Yahoo Japan.  They are all in Japanese, though.  The "Subnade" is the third map on that page, while other areas under Shinjuku are in maps #4-7.

Answer (score 6):

Building off of Kent's answer I was able to download the Yahoo maps and make a single image from them using https://github.com/lovasoa/dezoom.sh .

In particular, I used this command:

```
./dezoom.sh -x 931147 -y 111430 -X 931216 -Y 111397 "https://map.c.yimg.jp/m?mode=map-b1&r=1&x=%X&y=%Y&z=21&size=362"
```

The result is a 25,340 x 12,308 image. It's a 20.2MB JPEG. Not really sure the best way to share it.

Here's a screenshot of the JPEG when reduced down to a size small enough to fit on my screen:

[image: Shinjuku]

Here's that same image with some annotations:

[image: Shinjuku Annotated]

It'd be neat to have an above ground map for the same area to see what streets the exits correspond to.