# Miraikan visit and luggage storage possibility in Tokyo Shinkansen station?

Tags: tokyo, luggage-storage

I'll be leaving from Kyoto to Tokyo on Saturday morning, 30th July 2016, (can take the earliest Shinkansen). My flight back to India is at 9:30PM from Narita, Tokyo. I want to do the [Miraikan Museum](https://www.miraikan.jst.go.jp/en/) during the day. Can you please help with the following details?

1. Is this plan feasible?
2. Can I lock my luggage somewhere in Tokyo station?
   Are these facilities available?

Narita airport has this facility. However, going all the way till airport and coming back to the city will be a waste of time and money.

Comment: Good question ! Though I'd edit out #2 as you'll get mostly subjective answers, which are off-topic here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Place to store luggage for the day in Tokyo?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30849/place-to-store-luggage-for-the-day-in-tokyo)

Comment: Which shinkansen station? There are quite a few...

Comment: Also I'd highly recommend you split the questions up as per the [help] - it's best not to ask more than one question per post, or it'll get missed or closed as too broad.

Comment: Closing this is typical Travel.SE moderation overkill: this is a perfectly valid question if you skip #2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1- **Yes, absolutely.** The earliest shinkansen departs at 6:14 from Kyoto and arrives at 9:00 in Tokyo. Add in the ~40 minutes to get to Miraikan and you should be there at around 10:00.
To get to Narita on time (about 2 hours early), you'll have to leave at about 17:30, leaving you with a more than enough 7 hours to visit.

2- This is completely subjective, but if you enjoy technology and science, go for it. I found the exibits very interesting. You might also want to visit the nearby Gundam Front Tokyo

[image]

3- **Yes**, there are plenty of coin lockers in Tokyo station. These will cost you up to 500 yen depending on the size you choose.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Is the 500 yen per hour basis or per day?

Comment: Per 24 hours. Keep in mind that the rates might have changed, however, it shouldn't be more than 1000 yen at worst.

Comment: Pro tip: it will be slightly faster to get off the Shinkansen at Shinagawa and take Yamanote & Yurikamome lines to Miraikan.

Comment: @jpatokal, absolutely. I would be extremely surprised if there was no lockers at Shinagawa station.

Comment: It has plenty of lockers: http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/stations/e788.html

Comment: Most large stations have 3 sizes of lockers, S (￥300), M (￥500), L(￥700) and roll over at midnight each day (you should be gone before this). Further, Tokyo Station has Baggage Holding Facilities until the last Scheduled train (again well after you should have left).